# specman Temporal checking

Tags: specman

Going through the slides on temporal expressions, I came across this statement:

```
expect @buffer_full_e => eventually @int_e @clock_e else dut_error(
    “After the buffer was filled,an interrupt never occurred.”);
```

What is the significance of `eventually` here. Specifically, the difference if `eventually` was not used here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eventually` is kind of like an `if`/`else` in temporal language.  Either you see `@int_e @clock_e` *before the end of the simulation*, or else an error will fire as Specman runs checks at the end of test.